# How to unsubscribe and re-subscribe from a video stream using opentok web-rtc

Tags: webrtc, opentok

Using flash I had managed to subscribe / unsubscribe / and re-subscribe successfully in the past.
Now I'm using the web-rtc connection and when I try to manually re-subscribe to an unsubscribed stream it doesn't work.

Has anyone tried to do the same with more luck?

I use `session.subscribe(stream, stubDiv.id, subscriberProps);`

Then if I click to unsubscribe I use

```
for(var i = 0; i < subscribers.length; i++)
   session.unsubscribe(subscribers[i]);
```

and again to subscribe I provide the same object stream that I had stored before unsubscribing
to be able to re-subscribe `session.subscribe(stream, stubDiv.id, subscriberProps);`

and this last part is the one that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old issue, but I've had the same issue today and someone else might as well.
Like @songz said, when you unsubscribe it removes element from DOM.

Instead, when subscribing add `insertMode: 'append'` to properties:

```
let subscriberProps = {
  insertMode: 'append'
};
session.subscribe(stream, stubDiv.id, subscriberProps);
```

This will add another div inside your selected element and when you unsubscribe it will only remove new div.

Answer (score 0):

in your first `session.subscribe`, stubDiv gets replaced by video divs. In `session.unsubscribe`, stubDiv gets erased. When you call subscribe again with stubDiv (which doesn't exist now), there could be an error.